# React scroll start from bottom

Tags: reactjs

I have a chat page where I get a message from the server, I need to implement it so that the scroll of the starts from the last element. I use the `useRef` hook for scrolling, but my console gives an error **(TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null)**. but everything works correctly in the sandbox. I can not understand where is my mistake.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bell-7l4mm)

**React:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";


const TabPanelBody = ({messages}) => {

    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    };
    useEffect(scrollToBottom, []);

    return (
            <TabBody>
                {
                    messages.messages ? messages.messages.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Messages key={index} className={ data.my ? 'send-messages' : 'incoming-messages' }>
                                {data.message}
                                <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
                            </Messages>
                        )
                    }) : null
                }
            </TabBody>
    );
};
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check if there is a Current value

The error states that messagesEndRef.current is null. So make sure that there's a value inside the current before trying to run the function `scrollIntoView`.

```
messagesEndRef.current && messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: Thank's for feedback, error hide but scroll not started from buttom

Comment: useEffect(scrollToBottom, [messages]); this way is work ! Thanks Joe for feedback

Answer (score 0):

The ref isn't set yet when the `useEffect` is called. You have to check if the ref is set and then call the function.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";


const TabPanelBody = ({messages}) => {

    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }, [messagesEndRef.current]);

    return (
            <TabBody>
                {
                    messages.messages ? messages.messages.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Messages key={index} className={ data.my ? 'send-messages' : 'incoming-messages' }>
                                {data.message}
                                <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
                            </Messages>
                        )
                    }) : null
                }
            </TabBody>
    );
};
```

Comment: [messagesEndRef.current] - this way is not working, but thanks for feedback